# PHP __autoload not working within output buffer processing function

Tags: php, autoload, output-buffering

I have following dilemma:

```
ob_start('processBuffer');

function processBuffer($buffer){

    $betterBuffer = SomeClass::doSomething($buffer);
    return $betterBuffer;

}

function __autoload($className){

    if($className == 'SomeClass'){ include_once 'some_class.php'; }

}
```

If the class SomeClass has to be loaded within processBuffer for the first time, it does not work, but it does work if it has had to be loaded before the processBuffer function is executed. Why is that? Currently, to circumvent this issue, I have to do the following:

```
__autoload('SomeClass');
ob_start('processBuffer');
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call the `__autoload()` function directly; simply defining it should be enough for PHP to call it. However, PHP recommend not using `__autoload` any more; instead you should write functions and pass them into `spl_autoload_register()`. This is better for a number of ways, including allowing you to have multiple autoload functions which wasn't possible with the old `__autoload()` mechanism.

Comment: It's even worth to mention, that once _anything_ calls `spl_autoload_register()` `-_autoload()` gets completely disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by how PHP is layered internally. Your buffer processing function is called at the end of the execution stack, during the output stage. It's similar in that way to error handling functions, which are better documented regarding what they can and can't do. For instance (although I haven't tested this), I expect the buffer processing function also can't echo stuff (well, it can, but the output probably doesn't go anywhere).

Comment: Your absolutely right about the last bit, any output in an output handler will cause a fatal error: "Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers."

Comment: Yep, although for that last bit, the text to be echoed can instead simply be appended to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - "Fully Object Oriented".

In this case all buffering procedures are controlled from inside the class.

```
class SomeClass{
    public function __construct(){
        ob_start();
        //. . .
        return (0);
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        // . . . 
        ob_end_flush();
        return (0);
    }
}
```

Option 2 - "`__autoload()`".

Buffering is outside the class, but starts inside the __autoload() magic function.

```
function __autoload($class){
    ob_start();
    if($class == 'SomeClass'){ 
        include_once 'some_class.php'; 
    }
}

$c = new SomeClass();
// . . .
ob_end_flush();
```

As you can see in http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php , the `ob_start()` callable function will be called at `ob_end_flush()`.

Comment: I'm afraid option 2 might generate a huge ob stack (one ob layer for each class loaded via `__autoload()`). Option 1 is consistent, and it might or might not work, depending on the OP's needs -- but have you actually tested flushing from within a destructor? Sounds iffy (although it might work).

Comment: I am using buffering in my projects in 'Option 1' way with only difference, I am calling flush in public method different from __destruct. I am using buffer cancelation and output size measurements implementations. Everything works just fine.